# Unable to understand proper use of randomSeed() in custom functions

Tags: processing, p5.js

The random value is coming out to be different even when randomSeed() is initialised inside the setup() method.

For example:

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
  randomSeed(400);
  console.log(random(100));
}

function draw() {
  console.log(random(100));
  check();
  noLoop();
}

function check(){
  console.log(random(100));
}
```

Here, the three functions are giving different random values. Similarly, if I have a couple of functions like `funcA, funcB, funcC` etc, how to get a same random value throughout the program?

Similarly, if I am using noise() function, is there a way to get the same noise value every time the program is run when I am adding noiseSeed() in the setup() function?

Comment: There's an easy way to reuse a random number repeatedly throughout a run of the program. Call `n = random(100)` at the start of your program and use it repeatedly throughout the program. Seeding is when you want the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers. It's usually used to make random behavior reproducible. A RNG that always returns the same number on every run and call is useless--that's just a constant/literal number. If this isn't it, can you clarify what you're trying to achieve? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "The random value is coming out to be different"?

If you mean, that each call to `random(100)` results in a different value, that is the [expected behavior](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomSeed)!

Each call to `random(100)` results in a random value, but if you restart the program, **you will get the same values again**.

For me, your program results in

```
39.10889436956495
56.007297383621335
70.2842695871368
```

Every single time I run it.
If you remove `randomSeed(400);`, every time you start the program, the values will be different.

If you want `random(100)` to always return the same value, don't use the function, just replace it with the value you want.

But if by "The random value is coming out to be different" you mean, that running the program multiple times will result in different output for you, then something is broken in your setup.